# share video mp4 using pending intent notification

Tags: java, android, xml

i want to share a video mp4 using pending intent. I wrote this code

```
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Path/Path2/"+ecc);

            if(file.exists())
            {
            String path = file.toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/mp4");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mIntent.setType("video/mp4");
            mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
            PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, 0);
            notificationBuilder.addAction (android.R.drawable.ic_input_add, "SHARE", p);
            }
```

When I click share,the activity is loaded to share the file, but if I select whats app I get an error: failed sharing. why? where is the error?

Comment: We don't know. We don't see an error. Post stacktrace.

Comment: can you post an examle for share video from notification?